# How to display one 3d model on top of another in WPF?

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have 2 `ModelVisual3D`s in my scene, one is imported from a file and the other one is `ScreenSpaceLines3D` from `3DTools` package. Problem is, this line is inside my model and I need it to be shown on top of my model.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding `ScreenSpaceLines3D` to `Viewport3D` before actually adding a model worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of WPF is that elements are composable - in particular, if you want one element to appear "on top of" another, it's just a matter of encapsulating them both in 1x1 `Grid` element (the z-order can even be explicitly specified).

Comment: As I understood, it's not possible to add Grid inside Viewport3D (which displays these models).

Comment: @serge1peshcoff, how about putting two `Viewport3D`'s inside a `Grid`?